# Cassandra DB Design

Tags: nosql, schema, cassandra

I come from RDBMS background and designing an app with Cassandra as backend and I am unsure of the validity and scalability of my design.

I am working on some sort of rating/feedback app of books/movies/etc. Since Cassandra has the concept of flexible column families (sparse structure), I thought of using the following schema:

```
user-id (row key): book-id/movie-id (dynamic column name) - rating (column value)
```

If I do it this way, I would end up having millions of columns (which would have been rows in RDBMS) though not essentially associated with a row-key, for instance:

```
user1: {book1:Rating-Ok; book1023:good; book982821:good}
user2: {book75:Ok;book1023:good;book44511:Awesome}
```

Since all column families are stored in a single file, I am not sure if this is a scalable design (or a design at all!). Furthermore there might be queries like `"pick all 'good' reviews of 'book125'"`.
What approach should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This design is perfectly scalable. Cassandra stores data in sparse form, so empty cells don't consume disk space.

The drawback is that cassandra isn't very good in indexing by value. There are secondary indexes, but they should be used only to index a column or two, not each of million of columns.

There are two options to address this issue:

- Materialised views (described, for example, here: http://maxgrinev.com/2010/07/12/do-you-really-need-sql-to-do-it-all-in-cassandra/). This allows to build some set of predefined queries, probably quite complex ones.
- Ad-hoc querying is possible with some sort of map/reduce job, that effectively iterates over the whole dataset. This might sound scary, but still it's pretty fast: Cassandra stores all data in SSTables, and this iterating might be implemented to scan data files sequentially.

Answer (score 2):

Start from a desired set of queries and structure your column families to support those views.  Especially with so few fields involved, each CF can act cheaply as its own indexed view of your data.  During a fetch, the key will partition the data ultimately to one specific Cassandra node that can rapidly stream a set of wide rows to your app server in a pre-determined order.  This plays to one of Cassandra's strengths, as the fragmentation of that read on physical media (when not cached) is extremely low compared to bouncing around the various tracks and sectors on an indexed search of an RDBMS table.

One useful approach when available is to select your key to segment the data such that a full scan of all columns in that segment is a reasonable proposition, and a good rough fit for your query.  Then, you filter what you don't need, even if that filtering is performed in your client (app server).  All reviews for a movie is a good example.  Even if you filter the positive reviews or provide only recent reviews or a summary, you might still reasonably fetch all rows for that key and then toss what you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is if you can figure out how to partition data(by time, by category), playOrm offers a solution of doing S-SQL into a partition which is very fast.  It is very much like an RDBMS EXCEPT that you partition the data to stay scalable and can have as many partitions as you want.  partitions can contain millions of rows(I would not exceed 10 million rows though in a partition).

later,
Dean